# Distributions derivative (Generalized Functions)

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I want to find second derivative of $P.V. \frac{1}{x}$. And solution is
$$\langle \left(\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}\right)'', \varphi \rangle
= -\langle \left(\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}\right)', \varphi' \rangle
= \operatorname{pv}\int \frac{\varphi'(x)-\varphi'(0)}{x^2} \ dx
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\varphi'(x)-\varphi'(0)}{x^2} \ dx \\
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left(
\left[ \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi'(0)x-\varphi(0)}{x^2} \right]_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}
+ \left[ \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi'(0)x-\varphi(0)}{x^2} \right]_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \\
+ 2 \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi'(0)x-\varphi(0)}{x^3} \ dx
\right) \\
= 2\operatorname{pv}\int \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi'(0)x-\varphi(0)}{x^3} \ dx.$$

The question is why the below lim is equal to 0? I think it has to do with the space where generalized functions are defined. I tried brute force but it didn't work because of the uncertainties that arise.

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left(
\left[ \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi'(0)x-\varphi(0)}{x^2} \right]_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}
+ \left[ \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi'(0)x-\varphi(0)}{x^2} \right]_{\epsilon}^{\infty}
\right) \\$$

Any help would be great!

Comment: Look at "Taylor expansion" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the theory of distributions, $\phi$ is smooth and of compact suport.  And the limit is zero precisely since $\phi\in C_C^\infty$.

Using Taylor's theorem with the Peano form of the remainder, we have as $x\to 0$

$$\phi(x)-\phi'(0)x-\phi(0)=o(x^2)$$

where $o(1)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

Moreover, we have as $x\to \pm\infty$

$$\phi(x)-\phi'(0)x-\phi(0)=O(x)$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: can u pls explain it? Like we use this big O notations?

Comment: @Margaret Sure.  I used both [Little o](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html) and [Big O](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Big-ONotation.html) notations, the definitions of which you'll find in the references provided herein this comment/reply.  Just click the links.